# Как удалить перевод строки в OpenOffice?

Tags: open-office

В ячейке имеется многострочный текст, необходимо перевести в одну строку.

Comment: https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Writer.%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA_%D0%B8_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0:_%D0%A7%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8B

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В OpenOffice Writer выполните

1. Выберите `Правка - Найти и заменить... Ctrl+F`;
2. Для расширения диалогового окна нажмите `Детали`;
3. Установите флажок `Регулярное выражение`;
4. В поле `Найти` введите `\n` (Управляющий  символ представляющий разрыва строки. Вставляется комбинацией клавиш `Shift+Enter`), который требуется использовать найти;
   [image: Найти]
5. В поле `Заменить на` введите символ на который будет производиться замена. Например - пробел;
6. Нажмите `Заменить` или `Заменить все`.
7. Было:
   [image: Было]
8. Стало:[image: Стало]